# SAS The OLEDB engine cannot be found

Tags: sql, sas, connection, ssms, oledb

I do not know anything about SAS but I need to use it to export data from SSMS. I inherited an example previously used but am getting errors when inputting the SSMS information. I am trying to connect SAS to my local database but keep getting Error: The OLEDB engine cannot be found. But when I check SSMS it does show the OLEDB engine there.
I am currently testing how connection works because I will then need to connect SAS with our actual database server.
Screenshot of the SSMS showing OLEDB Provider and others:
[Provider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M03xK.png)

Screenshot of SSMS information:
[SSSM connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uI5B.png)

Screenshot of Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUZWQ.png)

Can someone who knows this stuff please help me figure this out, I am wondering if I should do anything on SAS. I have noticed there is an option to connect via a new Library but that also gives me the same error message. I have no instructions on how to connect the SSMS to SAS so anything will help me. Thanks

[New Library Connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXeq6.png)

UPDATE:
I downloaded the latest OLEDB provider from here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15
But still not success and running Proc Sentinit does not show the OLEDB provider. Tom, you mentioned I need to have have SAS/Access to OLEDB licensed, I guess I do not, I have SAS/ACCESS Interface to ODBC. Can I still connect using OLEDB? I am trying to download SAS OLEDB Driver, do you think it will still work with my current license? I do not think I can get a different license which is why I want to make it work. Below is a screenshot of what I have:
[SAS License Info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzD5e.png)

Comment: Do you have SAS/Access to OLEDB licensed? Run PROC SETINIT to check.  If so do you have it installed? Run PROC PRODUCT_STATUS to check.

Comment: it looks like I do not, but i thought I did since I saw the name on my SSMS, below is what I have after checking. Il download the free OLEDB driver and see what happens. But it should just be that simple right?

Comment: Product expiration dates:
---Base SAS Software
29SEP2067 (CPU A)
---SAS/STAT
29SEP2067 (CPU A)
---SAS/GRAPH
29SEP2067 (CPU A)
---SAS/Secure 168-bit
29SEP2067 (CPU A)
---SAS/Secure Windows
29SEP2067 (CPU A)
---SAS Enterprise Guide
29SEP2067 (CPU A)
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files
29SEP2069 (CPU A)
---SAS/ACCESS Interface to ODBC
29SEP2069 (CPU A)
---SAS Workspace Server for Local Access
29SEP2067 (CPU A)
---High Performance Suite
29SEP2067 (CPU A)

Comment: Can you use an ODBC driver to connect to that remote database?  Looks like you have that licensed.

Comment: Tom, I will give that a try. I was trying to avoid that route since the person before me had it using OLEDB...since I know nothing, I am trying to avoid as much change as possible, from what I read, ODBC requires more than changing the script format?

Comment: Hey Tom, I am finding different ways to connect to SQL Server using the ODBC driver and and getting errors, I also read in a guide that I also need do some configuration in  Control Panel -> System and Security -> Administrative Tools...is this true? Can you please provide me where to find the correct ODBC connection? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can read SAS datasets using the free OleDB driver (and ODBC) from SAS. Download it and install it. SAS needs SAS Access/OleDB to write to an OleDB datasource. Your best bet is to read the SAS datasets using SSMS vs trying to push them to SSMS. CozyRoc also makes an SSMS component that handles SAS datasets.

Comment: Hey Alan, I have SAS/ACCESS Interface to ODBC, can I still use the free OLEDB driver from SaS and make this work? Since I am new to SaS, I am trying to use the same scripts and connection that has been previously used. I am currently attempting to Donwload from https://support.sas.com/downloads/package.htm?pid=2169# but its failing.

Comment: Use ODBC then vs OleDB. ODBC is more widely supported. Go to https://www.connectionstrings.com/ to find what you need. Also, I am not sure what you are downloading. look for the free ODBC or OleDB drivers from SAS. link: https://support.sas.com/downloads/browse.htm?fil=&cat=40

Comment: Thank you, my admin has installed the ODBC driver but I am now having a hard to getting the correct connection. The documentation found here https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Communities-Library/Accessing-a-Microsoft-SQL-Server-Database-from-SAS-under/ta-p/785848 is telling me that I first need to set up an ODBC Data Source connection through my control panel....is this true? Thanks for the help, I am kind of all over the place finding solutions because I need to have this working next week

Comment: That is not true. if you are going to use it a lot, yes, you should have it defined in your ODBC connections. However, I don't know what your environment is so that may/may not help. In a SAS Grid environment, it needs to connect from the server. However, you can do it directly without any setup. See the LIBNAME NOPROMPT option. Example: libname TEST odbc noprompt = "server=MYSQLServer;DRIVER=SQL Server;Trusted Connection=yes" QUALIFIER = Mydatabase SCHEMA = Myschema;

Answer (score 0):

1. The SAS OBDC driver is distributed with the **SAS Universal Viewer** which you can download for free after making a free account at sas.com.
2. The OBDC driver that you install must match the bitness of the application calling it.  The 32bit and 64bit versions of the Universal Viewer install
3. If the bitness of the app and the driver do not match, it will appear as if the driver is not installed.

[image: SAS Universal Viewer download page]